# ¿Es posible re-dimensionar una imagen en una publicación?

Tags: soporte, faq, imágenes

¿Es posible cambiar el tamaño de una imagen en una respuesta (o pregunta) en StackOverflow en Español?

Por ejemplo, la primera versión de *[DISTANCIA ANDROID STUDIO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/37170/1)* muestra una imagen que, a mi parecer, es demasiado grande.

¿Hay alguna manera de mostrarla más pequeña sin tener que guardarla, re-dimensionarla en un editor y subirla de nuevo?

Traducción de [esta pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/149992) en meta.SO

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 18):

Todas las imágenes que se suben se almacenan en servidores *imgur*, se puede [ajustar la URL](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/please-try-using-smaller-versions-of-images) para mostrar distintos tamaños [si la original es muy grande](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-pho/101446#101446).

Donde la original sea tan grande como esta:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofO.jpg

Puedes añadir distintos caracteres antes de la extensión del archivo:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofO█.jpg
                               ^
                               aquí
```

Para tamaño (los caracteres que están en `negrita`):

- Original: No se agrega nada.
- `large`: Grande.
- `medium`: Mediano
- `small`: Pequeño.
- `thumbnail`: Miniatura.

O puedes finalmente hacerlo con el buen `HTML` para forzar que se re-dimensione del lado del cliente:

```html
<img src="http://example.com/path-to-ghosts.jpg" width="100" height="100">
```

---

Algunos ejemplos a continuación con la misma imagen:

Original (sin cambios):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofO.jpg
```

[image: Original]

Grande (**`l`**):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofOl.jpg
                               ^
```

[image: Large]

Mediano (**`m`**):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofOm.jpg
                               ^
```

[image: Medium]

Pequeño (**`s`**):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofOs.jpg
                               ^
```

[image: Small]

Miniatura (**`t`**):

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BofOt.jpg
                               ^
```

[image: Thumbnail]

Basada en [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25052/149992) y [Hidden features of Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286545/209901) en inglés.

Comment: Hacía tiempo que me había hecho esta pregunta. Sin embargo, nunca se me ocurrió preguntar sobre ello. ¡¡Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: Muy útil, muchas gracias Juan!